# Jersy's SelectableEntityFilteringFeature Not Working

Tags: java, jersey

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.22.2/examples/entity-filtering-selectable) to enable dynamic filtering in `Jersey`.

My configuration:

```
resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
resourceConfig.register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
resourceConfig.property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "select");
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Using select query-param doesn't select the specified fields. Plus, `resourceConfig.isEnabled(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class)` returns false.

Below are my dependecies:

```
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.containers" name="jersey-container-jetty-http" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.containers" name="jersey-container-servlet-core" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.core" name="jersey-server" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" name="jersey-bean-validation" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.media" name="jersey-media-multipart" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" name="jersey-declarative-linking" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" name="jersey-entity-filtering" rev="2.22.1"/>
 <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.media" name="jersey-media-json-jackson" rev="2.22.1"/>
```

Comment: I'm running a standalone application, not WAR. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: Sorry I was just looking at the dependencies. I completely overlooked the jetty container dependency.