# Dynamic attribute filtering based on query params with Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, api, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to filter out certain properties of the response body generated by *Jackson* based on a query param of the request

Jersey endpoint

```
@Path("zoo/{id}")
@GET
public Response getZoos(@PathParam("id") String id, 
@QueryParam("animalsFilter") List<String> animals) {
    ....
    var zoos = Arrays.asList(zooDto1, zooDto2);
    return Response.ok().entity(zoos).build();
}
```

and the `ZooDto` looking like

```
public class ZooDto {
    private Zebra zebra;
    private Elephant elephant;
    ...
}
```

**Expected result:**

If the *query param* `animals` contains only `zebra` I am expecting the following JSON to be returned:

```
[
    {
        "zebra": {
        ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

If the *query param* `animals` contains `zebra` and `elephant` I am expecting the following JSON to be returned:

```
[
    {
        "zebra": {
        ...
        },
        "elephant": {
        ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

**Tried approaches so far:**

1. `@JsonInclude(value =...` is not working since I cannot access the list of `animals` to be filtered
2. `@JsonFilter("...` seems to work but I need to produce quite a lot of code for each filter looking like

```
public static class BeanFilterImpl extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {
    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(
    ...
```

3. `filterProvider.addFilter("filter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(animals));` was looking promising as well but I need to add this filter to the object mapper which I don't have available in my controller class where I receive `animals`.
   I have my ObjectMapper registered as `@Provider`:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
...
```

4. Making use of `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature` sounded like the right thing to do but configuring the app as required did not change anything (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585378/jersys-selectableentityfilteringfeature-not-working)). I might be doing something wrong here, `resourceConfig.isEnabled(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class)` is returning `false`:

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class MyAppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyAppConfig() {
        register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
        property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "select");
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
```

and my `build.gradle` contains

```
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-entity-filtering', version: '2.34'
```

When I am adding `select=elephant` to the query params, the whole (non-filtered) entity is returned.
Further, I am not sure if `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature` is working on a list of DTOs.

How can I realize this filtering feature without adding much code?

Comment: [Jersey actually has support for this out of the box](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @PaulSamsotha - I indeed tried this one already since it sounded like the right thing to do but after adding the configurations, nothing did change. I am not sure if I registered everything correctly though...

I added this as fourth solution I tried.

Comment: `resourceConfig.isEnabled(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class)` is returning false :/.
My dependencies are `Jersey 2.31` and `Jackson 2.12.3`

Comment: Have you read the _whole_ chapter and looked at _all_ the example usages?

Comment: I have in particular looked into `20.5. Entity Filtering based on dynamic and configurable query parameters` since `20.3.` and `20.4` do not seem to do what I require. I also added transitive dependencies defined in `20.1.`... :/